# How to increment value whenever same button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I would like int countHarry to keep incrementing by 1 whenever user clicks on "Vote Harry" button. The output will be written inside "data.txt". However, my data.txt will only show value as 1. Need advise. Thanks.

This is a .cshtml file.

Current output: Harry, 1
Expected output: Harry, 3 (where int value increases upon click each time)

```js
@{
    var result = "";
    int countJohn = 1;
    int countHarry = 1;

    if (IsPost)
    {
        var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/data.txt");

        if (Request["submit"] == "Vote Harry")
        {

            //var harry = Request["Harry"];

            var userData = "Harry" + "," + countHarry + Environment.NewLine;

            File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, userData);

            // countHarry += countHarry;  does not increases the count inside  .txt at all

            result = "Information saved.";
        }

        else if (Request["submit"] == "Vote John")
        {

            //var john = Request["John"];

            var userData = "John" + "," + (Int32.Parse("1")) + Environment.NewLine;

            File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, userData);

            result = "Information saved.";

            countJohn += 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elections</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Harry</td>
                    <td><input id="Harry" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Harry"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td><input id="John" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote John" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bryan</td>
                    <td><input id="Bryan" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Bryan" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jack</td>
                    <td><input id="Jack" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Jack" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (result != "")
            {
                <p>Result: @result</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (is this really js?) - put `countHarry` outside the if, so that it is accessible for all the other ifs

Comment: There is something wring with your snippet.Please correct it!

Comment: I have a couple of questions here.  I know you're asking about Harry, but is John working?  I'm guessing not but I thought I would ask.  If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the incremented count to export to the text file, yes?  If so, you need to increment the count before it's written to the text file.  If I misunderstood your request, please let me know and I'll try again.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes Doug F, what u are saying is correct!  Do u know how to increment before writing it? I need each person to have their individual increments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to define countHarry here:

```
@{
var result = "";
int countJohn = 1;
int countharry = 1;
```

Now you can reach countharry where you need because it's "global"..

Comment: i changed according to ur answers. I am still unable to print out 2,3,4... respectively.